# Python load json file with UTF-8 BOM header

Tags: python, json

I needed to parse files generated by other tool, which unconditionally outputs json file with UTF-8 BOM header (EFBBBF). I soon found that this was the problem, as Python 2.7 module can't seem to parse it:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = json.load(open('sample.json'))

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Removing BOM, solves it, but I wonder if there is another way of parsing json file with BOM header?

Comment: [Python : How to fix Unexpected UTF-8 BOM error when using json.loads](https://www.howtosolutions.net/2019/04/python-fixing-unexpected-utf-8-bom-error-when-loading-json-data/)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can open with `codecs`:

```
import json
import codecs

json.load(codecs.open('sample.json', 'r', 'utf-8-sig'))
```

or decode with `utf-8-sig` yourself and pass to `loads`:

```
json.loads(open('sample.json').read().decode('utf-8-sig'))
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using `io.open()` over `codecs.open()`: `json.load(io.open('sample.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'))`. The `io` module is more robust and faster.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for that comment, good to know. I found this discussion of the differences that might be useful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/s_eIyt3KoLE

Answer (score 39):

Simple! You don't even need to import `codecs`.

```
with open('sample.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `json.load(stream)` uses `json.loads(stream.read())` under the hood, it won't be that bad to write a small hepler function that lstrips the BOM:

```
from codecs import BOM_UTF8

def lstrip_bom(str_, bom=BOM_UTF8):
    if str_.startswith(bom):
        return str_[len(bom):]
    else:
        return str_

json.loads(lstrip_bom(open('sample.json').read()))
```

In other situations where you need to wrap a stream and fix it somehow you may look at inheriting from `codecs.StreamReader`.

Comment: Why not use the string strip function?

Comment: @SamStoelinga, since strip function receives not a prefix but a set of characters to remove. That it you need to either decode the byte-string into the `unicode` or use the approach above to be sure you left-strip only the UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: I'm getting an error that says 

    TypeError: expected str,bytes or os.Pathlike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Comment: @Zypps987, the snippet assumes python2 where `read()` returns bytes. To make the snippet work in python3 you will need to encode `BOM_UTF8` to 'utf-8'. But you don't need this, when you have `utf-8-sig` encoding.

Answer (score 4):

you can also do it with keyword **with**

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('samples.json', 'r', 'utf-8-sig') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

or better:

```
import io
with io.open('samples.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off, a very simple super high-tech solution that worked for me...

- Open the JSON file in your favorite text editor.
- Select-all
- Create a new file
- Paste
- Save.

BOOM, BOM header gone!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the BOM manually with Linux command.

First I check if there are `efbb bf` bytes for the file, with `head i_have_BOM | xxd`.

Then I run `dd bs=1 skip=3 if=i_have_BOM.json of=I_dont_have_BOM.json`.

`bs=1` process 1 byte each time, `skip=3`, skip the first 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using utf-8-sig   just with import json

```
with open('estados.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_file:
data = json.load(json_file)
print(data)
```