# Python split() not working as expected for first line in file

Tags: python, file

I have a large text file of data mined opinions and each is classified as positive, negative, neutral, or mixed. Every line begins with "+ ", "- ", "= ", or "* " which correspond to these classifiers. Additionally, lines that begin with "!! " represent a comment to ignore.

Below is a simple Python script that is just supposed to count each of the classifiers and ignore the comment lines:

```
classes = [0, 0, 0, 0] # "+", "-", "=", "*"

f = open("All_Classified.txt")
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    line = line.strip()
    classifier = line.split(" ")[0]

    if classifier == "+": classes[0] += 1
    elif classifier == "-": classes[1] += 1
    elif classifier == "=": classes[2] += 1
    elif classifier == "*": classes[3] += 1
    elif classifier == "!!": continue
    else: print "Line "+str(i+1)+": \""+line+"\""
f.close()

print classes
```

Here is a sample of the first 5 lines of "All_Classified.txt":

```
!! GROUP 1, 1001 - 1512
= 1001//CD TITLETITLE//NNP How//WRB many//JJ conditioners/conditioner/NNS do//VBP you//PRP have//VBP ?//. 
= 1002//CD I//PRP have//VBP two//CD different//JJ kinds/kind/NNS ,//, Garnier//NNP Fructis//NNP Triple//NNP Nutrition//NNP conditioner//NN ,//, and//CC Suave//NNP coconut//NN .//. 
= 1003//CD But//CC I//PRP think//VBP I//PRP have//VBP about//IN 8//CD bottles/bottle/NNS of//IN the//DT Suave//NNP coconut//NN My//PRP$ mom//NN gave/give/VBD me//PRP a//DT bunch//NN for//IN Christmas//NNP because//IN she//PRP was/be/VBD getting/get/VBG tired/tire/VBN of//IN me//PRP saying/say/VBG I//PRP was/be/VBD out//IN 
= 1004//CD TITLETITLE//NNP Need//VB a//DT gel//NN that//IN works/work/NNS ,//, 8//CD mo//NN ,//, post//NN ,//, ready//JJ to//TO relax//VB edges/edge/NNS ,//, HELP//NNP ,//,
```

For whatever reason my output is triggering the else statement during the first iteration as if it does not recognize the "!!", I am not sure why. I am getting this as output:

```
Line 1: "!! GROUP 1, 1001 - 1512"
[2986, 1034, 16278, 535]
```

Additionally, If I delete the first line from "All_Classified.txt" then it does not recognize the "=" of what would then be the first line. Not sure what has to be done for the first line to be recognized as expected.

**Edit (again)**: As Peter asked, here is the output if I replace `else: print "Line "+str(i+1)+": \""+line+"\""` with `else: print "Classifier "+classifier+ " Line "+str(i+1)+": \""+line+"\""`:

```
Classifier !! Line 1: "!! GROUP 1, 1001 - 1512"
[2986, 1034, 16278, 535]
```

**Edit**: First section using `xxd All_Classified.txt`:

```
0000000: efbb bf21 2120 4752 4f55 5020 312c 2031  ...!! GROUP 1, 1
0000010: 3030 3120 2d20 3135 3132 0d0a 3d20 3130  001 - 1512..= 10
0000020: 3031 2f2f 4344 2054 4954 4c45 5449 544c  01//CD TITLETITL
0000030: 452f 2f4e 4e50 2048 6f77 2f2f 5752 4220  E//NNP How//WRB
```

Comment: It seems that your code should be working fine. perhaps there's something weird in the file which you can't detect simply by `print`ing. In any case, `pdb` is your friend. Also, what OS are you running on? perhaps you can try converting file's newlines to your OS's native.

Comment: Are you _certain_ there's a space between '!!' and 'GROUP' and not, say, a tab? Your code works for me.

Comment: can you print classifier in `else: print ...` and show output?

Comment: Yes, I am certain it is a space. I just tried copy / pasting what I posted here as well (both code and the text file) and get the same output (other than the counts obviously)

Comment: @Peter, I edited my question with the output

Comment: @asimes I asked you to `else: print "Classifier "+classifier+ " Line "+str(i+1)+": \""+line+"\""`

Comment: @Peter, updated again

Comment: [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)?

Comment: Can you produce a hex dump of the first 40 bytes of your file, and include that in the question? (If you're on Linux/OSX, `xxd` would do the trick.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your input file isn't what it seems. For example, `classifier` could contain some control characters that are not shown when you print it (but which affect the comparison):

```
>>> classifier = '!\0!'
>>> print classifier
!!
>>> classifier == '!!'
False
```

**edit** There you have it:

```
0000000: efbb bf21 2120
         ^^^^ ^^
```

It's the [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), which becomes part of `classifier`.

Try opening the file using [`codecs.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) with `"utf-8-sig"` as the encoding (see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13156715/367273).

Comment: Thank you, would have never figured that out. After importing codecs I did `f = codecs.open("All_Classified.txt", 'r', 'utf-8-sig')` and it worked