# Python json raises ValueError exception on valid JSON

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON file, called `my_file.json`:

```
{
"t shirt": [
    "tee"
],
"neck": [
    "neckline"
],
"grey": [
    "gray"
]
}
```

I am reading it with:

```
f = open('my_file.json', 'r')
json.load(f)
```

I get the exception `ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")`, as if the file wasn't valid JSON, which it actually is (even checked it with a validator).

What's wrong?

Comment: Check for a BOM marker. The BOM marker is a Unicode character with code point U+FEFF that specifies the endianness of an Unicode text stream. It makes no sense for UTF-8 but some text editors put this in the beginning of the file (and it is invisible).

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156395/python-load-json-file-with-utf-8-bom-header

Comment: If you print the `repr` output of each line the file you will see exactly what is there

Comment: I think Paulo is correct, the above example should works without a problem.