# Loop action on list doesn't perform correctly on just the first item

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm just trying to remove the first 45 characters from every line in an imported text file and then write the results to a new text file. For some reason, only the first item in the list/line gets messed up and only the first 42 characters are removed.

I've encountered this issue a number of times before and never figured out why it was happening, could use some outside wisdom! Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
with codecs.open('FILE.txt', "r", encoding="utf-8") as inputfile:
        list1 = [line.strip() for line in inputfile]
        list1 = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in list1]
        for item in list1:
            list2.append(item[45:])
z = open('NEWFILE.txt', 'w');
z.write("\n".join(list2))
z.close()
```

Comment: Sounds like there are actually 3 extra invisible characters on that line.

Comment: Why are you slicing *after* you encode? You're chopping off 45 bytes, not 45 characters, when you do it that way.

Comment: wouldn't it be a BOM header problem? BOM headers are part of the encoding and are ... 3 bytes long on the first line...

Comment: check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156395/python-load-json-file-with-utf-8-bom-header

Comment: @user2357112 Not sure, I switched the slice to appear before the encoding but the first line is now removing only the first 44 characters and not 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That UTF-8 stuff along with the 3 bytes shift in the first line looks very much like extra BOM header.

```
>>> from codecs import BOM_UTF8
>>> len(BOM_UTF8)
3
```

BOM header is detected by most text editors and is not directly visible (unless you use a text editor).

I propose you change your inner loop like this:

```
for item in list1:
    list2.append(item[45+len(codecs.BOM_UTF8) if item.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8) else 45:])
```

so if line (first line) starts with the BOM header, you add the 3 extra bytes

Or may directly before you encode your full string:

```
list1 = [(x[len(codecs.BOM_UTF8):] if x.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8) else x).encode('utf-8') for x in list1]
```

BOM-strip code taken from this Q/A: [Python load json file with UTF-8 BOM header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156395/python-load-json-file-with-utf-8-bom-header)

Comment: Was already perusing the link you provided in your initial reply, but thank you for the more in-depth explanation. The loop line you provided works perfectly

Comment: if my post was useful, then you can accept the answer. If you figured out yourself, then you don't have to accept it of course.