# Importing json files on GUI using python. getting JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, anaconda

[Link to the .json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_5UMwE-SyTd8jqViNjqhteIEXZtmG_6i/view) -> This is the link to the .json file.

I am making a Python based project and what I am trying to do here is to make use of a .json file. However when I tried to import it to use it with the GUI I got the following error.

Thank you in advance.
 Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-31816de2c4db>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Akshita/pyex/Webmap/Gui.py', wdir='C:/Users/Akshita/pyex/Webmap')

 File "C:\Users\Akshita\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
   execfile(filename, namespace)

 File "C:\Users\Akshita\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

 File "C:/Users/Akshita/pyex/Webmap/Gui.py", line 12, in <module>
   data=json.load(open(r"C:\Users\Akshita\pyex\Webmap\world.json"))

 File "C:\Users\Akshita\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

  File "C:\Users\Akshita\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
   return _default_decoder.decode(s)

 File "C:\Users\Akshita\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

 File "C:\Users\Akshita\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

---

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon May 21 10:15:01 2018

@author: Akshita
"""

from tkinter import *
import json
import difflib
from difflib import get_close_matches
data=json.load(open(r"C:\Users\Akshita\pyex\Webmap\world.json"))
window=Tk()
window.title("Webmap")
l1=Label(window,text="Name_of_place")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)
val=StringVar()
e=Entry(window,textvariable=val)
e.grid(row=0,column=1)
be=Button(window,text="Enter",command=entry)
be.grid(row=0,column=2)
def entry():

    w= e_val.get()

    w=w.title()

    if w in data:
     t.insert("Data matched")
    elif len(get_close_matches(w,data.keys(),cutoff=0.8))>0:
        t.insert("Did you mean %s instead?" %get_close_matches(w,data.keys())[0])  

t=Text(window,height=3,width=20)
t.grid(row=1,column=1)
by=Button(window,text="Yes",command=yeah)
by.grid(row=2,column=1)
def yeah():
    t.insert("Processing")

bn=Button(window,text="No",command=nah)
bn.grid(row=2,column=2)

def nah():
    t.insert("No such Data")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have posted the complete error. :)

Comment: I have posted the complete error. :)

Comment: show your .json file

Comment: your JSON is invalid

Comment: But I have used this file in my other projects.  Can you please tell me whether my code is correct? Also I have used the same .json file in other project and it worked. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error in your code comes from line `data=json.load(....`. But i've tried to run the script with your example json and it works with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your JSON file is invalid - the sequence of brackets at the end is incorrect.

The end should look like this:

```
... <previous data> ... ,[2.96361,36.802216]]]}}]}
```

You can use online or IDE JSON checkers to validate your file.

---

#### update

Got your full json file.

It turns out that it has UTF-8 BOM header. Try to `load()` it this way:

```
import json
import codecs

data = json.load(codecs.open('tst.json', 'r', 'utf-8-sig'))
print(data)
```

Related SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13156715/2315573

Comment: The example I gave was just an instance of the .json file. The file ends with the brackets in the same sequence you specified.

Comment: Error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value` means that the JSON is invalid and parser cannot parse it. Can you give us an exact json file, not an example?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow abd I don't know how to attach a file. Can you please help me?

Comment: if it's big enough, you may use a file hosting and paste a link