# Reading a response from request.get

Tags: python

This might be a stupid question but I am trying to read the content of the following link:

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/Dataflow/"
seriesids = requests.get(url)
x = seriesids.json()
```

but I get the following error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python load json file with UTF-8 BOM header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156395/python-load-json-file-with-utf-8-bom-header)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing slash at the end :)

```
url = "http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/Dataflow"
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Please approve if it works for ya, otherwise let us know if you need more info :)