# Unable to read a json file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json file and I'm trying to read the file using the below code

```
import json

with open('sample.json') as file:
     data = json.load(file)
```

and I'm getting the below error

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

My guess was the json file was not valid so I opened the json file in a text editor and copied the data and tried to validate it via online json validator and the online tool confirmed that its a valid json.

So i wanted to understand what my notebook is reading when I read the file so I tried to print the string and surprisingly the string had a lot of unwanted values such as **\n** and **ï»¿** etc which is definately not there when I open the json file in the notepad.

```
with open('sample.json') as file:
     test_text = file.read()
print(test_text)
```

o/p  I get in python notebook when I try to print the read file:

```
'ï»¿[{"iteration" : {"id" :"value"},
"filename" : "testfile.json"
}\n,
{"iteration" : {"id" :"value1"},
"filename" : "testfile2.json"
}\n]'
```

Please advise what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this

Comment: The characters at the beginning look like UTF-8 BOM. Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156395/python-load-json-file-with-utf-8-bom-header

Comment: @AndrejKesely thank you very much the Encoding : utf-8-sig did the trick. Out of curiosity what are these encoding patterns?

Comment: what process creates this file, or where does this file come from?

Comment: @CobyC the file was created on Azure DataFactory  and encoded in UTF-8 format

Comment: @Stramzik see the last two paragraphs of [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode) from the Python codecs docs.

Comment: @Stramzik I see that you managed to get it to work using the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

use the encoding parameter and set it to `utf-8-sig`

```
with open('sample.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

original answer comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156395/python-load-json-file-with-utf-8-bom-header)